# How to peek data from a stream without consuming it

Tags: rust, stream

I need to process a stream depending on the content of the first 7 bytes. I figured that I could simply use the [`Peekable`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.13/futures/stream/struct.Peekable.html) trait.

I've converted my receiver channel into a peekable to obtain a borrow to the first message:

```rust
let mut peek: Peekable<UnboundedReceiver<StreamMessage>> = stream.peekable();
if let Some(peeked_data) = Pin::new(&mut peek).peek().await {
    // inspect peeked_data
    let mut reclaimed_stream = peek.into_inner();
    if let Some(owned_data) = reclaimed_stream.next().await {
        // process data
    }
}
```

However, with the above approach, the reclaimed stream never returns any data. Replacing the call on `reclaimed_stream` to be try_next results in a `TryRecvErr` telling me the receiver channel is empty.

This seems to contradict the intention of the `Peekable` trait, so I assume that I have done something wrong in my implementation, but I can't find many examples of a similar approach. Could someone tell me what is wrong which the above approach & why?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

This question was cross posted to the [rust subreddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/lwy38h/how_to_peek_data_from_a_stream_without_consuming/gpjua0h/) where it was already answered.

TL;DR - the `Peekable` owns the data which it has peeked. By discarding the `Peekable` to obtain the original stream (`into_inner`), the data owned is also dropped.